# After I 'download' apps through docker, do I really have it in my computer? If so, where are they stored?

Tags: docker

For example, if I build an image through dockerfile which contains nginx and php-frm, do I really have them in my computer? Where can I find the related directories?

Comment: There's a very good tutorial here... https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=zJ6WbK9zFpI&t=1182s

Comment: Thanks! It helps a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are stored on your computer (unless you have some special configuration like storing them by NFS somewhere). You may see location of docker images by calling

```
docker info
```

and looking for *Docker Root Dir* line

```
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
```

To verify this go to this directory - its content is usually quite big.

This [tutorial](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/where-are-docker-images-stored-docker-container-paths-explained/) lists some common locations on various OS:

- Ubuntu: /var/lib/docker/
- Fedora: /var/lib/docker/
- Debian: /var/lib/docker/
- Windows: C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop
- MacOS: ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/vms/0/

Comment: I got another question here. If I build two images, and both of them have nginx, will nginx be downloaded twice in my computer?

Comment: no, see `docker imges` and you will see one `nginx`, unless new version, different args were used